Scifi fantasy book - miniature people riding insect shaped vehicles
I read this book when I was a teen, in the early 2000s. It is a book about a boy waking up and suddenly he is in a society of miniature people. This society of small people ride advanced vehicles shaped as common insects in a bid to hide from regularly sized humans.
At the end of the book the boy visits his actual comatose body in a hospital after a high stakes race against time, riding on one of these mechanized insects, and gets his miniature body and insects crushed. He is then transferred back into his comatose body as his miniature self perishes.

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. When exactly did you read this? We don't know how old you are, so we have no idea when you were a teen

hi I read it in the early 2000s

Thanks for that :) if you remember any extra details please [edit] them in. Here is a very useful post that might help jog your memory if you're stuck

sorry it has been ages, all I know is that it is a series of books and in this series of books. The miniature people were not happy with the normal sized people for their pollution of the environment and were in a secret war with them. In one of the books they tried to control a normal sized human using some form of mind control tool. Honestly I only read the first and been meaning to finish the series.

Oh shoot, I just remembered the books title. It is The Dreamwalker's Child by Steve Voake.

@Eric: You should write your answer below and accept it to close the question.

Just remembered the book' title, The Dreamwalker's Child by Steve Voake.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please [edit] your answer to add more details on how this work answers the question. You can find tips on how to write a good identification answer and what details to add in our guide.

Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. However, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.
